# Unsatisfied link error when calling from NetBeans package

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface

I have developed a linux shared library to communicate with pos terminals. The library has been developed using C language, and the routines are imported in to a java program using JNI interface. I have tested the library with the simple Java class it works perfectly.how ever when I try to develop a front end java application using netbeans it pops up `Unsatisfied link error` . so i recompiled the library with the package name embedded in ever function call with in the shared library and the issue was resolved. I found the package name causes the specific error. Is there a way to come out from this problem. because I cant ask the client to keep the package name static. it should be able to change as they need. I tried several compiler and linker directive but failed ..The current working library has been compiled using the following command

```
gcc -shared -o libecr.so -fpic ecr.c -lusb-1.0
```

This compiles with no errors in Fedora 14.

- `libecr.so` is my shared library
- `ecr.c` is the source code file
- `lusb`  is the `libusb` which is referenced by `ecr` code

Comment: Please add an after/before of the package names in question (or if you don't want to disclose the full names, a similar example) to see what the change was.

Comment: (Also: If I were you I'd probably give your clients a proper Java API too that hides the JNI part altogether, and provides you an extra layer of abstraction. Depending on the situation, this can make your life easier in maintaining the code on a long term, during the lifecycle of the library. Just think of it: if you want to change something, and you need to change the JNI code, your client will have to change the client side. If you have a layer of Java above it, most changes can be followed by that, saving time for you and your client)

Comment: Thank you for your reply...you are suggesting that to provide another java class which wraps the library callings. ??? yeah that would be a good solution. I will try that too.. but i have seen another shared library which is not dependent on the package name. I dnt know how it would have been compiled